# regular expression for line length and multiline input

Tags: regex, multiline

I have tried to create a regular expression that would match if the input text has  max 3 lines of text, at most 10 characters per line, and characters are all uppercase.
So this string should match: `"AA\n\nAA"`

but this shouldn't
`"A12c"`

I thought this would work: (I enabled multiline in Pattern)

`(^[A-Z]{0,10}$){0,3}`

but it doesn't, it only matches if the text is jut one-liner.

I cannot understand what is wrong with the expression - isn't the {0,3} quantifier applied correclty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to match the line terminator:

```
(^[A-Z]{0,10}$\r?\n?){0,3}
```

should work, assuming that the option for `^` and `$` to match start/end-of-line and not start/end-of-string is set.

If you need the regex to fail if there are more than 3 lines in your string, you can force the regex engine to match the entire string or not at all by surrounding it with `\A` and `\z` anchors:

```
\A(^[A-Z]{0,10}$\r?\n?){0,3}\z
```

However, not all regex flavors support these start-of-string/end-of-string anchors.

Comment: thanks, that works! I thought the line terminator was implicit when $ was present

Comment: And what about exact number of lines ?
Say 4 lines with 35 characters each.

Like regex should fail if input text has more than 4 lines.

Comment: Depends on how you use the regex. In Java, the `matches()` method will fail if it's not possible to match the entire text. Otherwise, add `\A` and `\z` anchors to the start/end of the regex. They will ensure that the entire string is matched.